# skeleton tracking on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: openi-tracker, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04. I have Microsoft Kinect first version. I installed openni and nite 1.5.2.23 but I couldn't find a ROS package for skeleton tracking by using nite and openni because I couldn't install openni_tracker for ROS Kinetic. Is there any other way to use Kinect in order to track a skeleton of a body or do I need to change ROS version to Indigo?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256001/skeleton-tracking-on-ubuntu-16.04/) by [mehmet](https://answers.ros.org/users/29539/mehmet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-03-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to clone the [openni_tracker](https://github.com/ros-drivers/openni_tracker) package into an active workspace and build it from source using `catkin_make`. I've built and run it on Kinetic with no issues.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2017-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mehmet](https://answers.ros.org/users/29539/mehmet/) on 2017-03-02**:
Yeah, it worked! Thank you very much Mr. Schultz, I had spend many days to do that!

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-03-02**:
[Asked for making a release](https://github.com/ros-drivers/openni_tracker/issues/9#issuecomment-283827241).

**Comment by [Dhagash Desai](https://answers.ros.org/users/26869/dhagash-desai/) on 2017-09-29**:
Can you share how you installed the OpenNI package I getting many errors I am using the same version as you. Please help

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-09-29**:
@Dhagash Desai please open a new question instead, otherwise your question here doesn't get much views. Also, going through our [support guideline](http://wiki.ros.org/Support) may help.

**Comment by [Dhagash Desai](https://answers.ros.org/users/26869/dhagash-desai/) on 2017-09-30**:
Thanks for the reply I got that thing

**Comment by [iamshimon](https://answers.ros.org/users/40541/iamshimon/) on 2019-03-20**:
hey, I have managed to install openni_tracker but can't find the NiTE package . Is it still available or is it owned by Apple ?.
Are there any other alternatives to obtain skeletal data from Kinect v1 sensor on ROS kinetic.?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2019-03-20**:
@iamshimon Please open a new question. Otherwise your question won't get answered.